# C# приведение string к любому типу

Tags: c#

Имеется вот такой метод:

```
private static object InvokeMethod(Type type, MethodInfo method, HttpRequest request)
    {
        var parametersValues = new Json(request.EntityBody);
        var parametersVariables = method.GetParameters();
        int length = parametersVariables.Length;
        string[] parameters = new string[method.GetParameters().Length];
        int i=0;
        foreach(var parameter in parametersVariables)
        {
            parametersValues.variables.TryGetValue(parameter.Name, out parameters[i++]);
        }
        return method.Invoke(type, (object[])parameters);
    }
```

Параметры метода имеют какие-то произвольные типы. В parametersValues хранится IDictionary , в котором ключи - название переменных, а значение - это их значение, но в строковом формате.

Вопрос: как преобразовать значение переменных из строки в нужный тип динамически?

Comment: `System.Convert.ChangeType` преобразовует, могут правда возникнуть проблемы с точка/запятая при преобразовании дробных.

Comment: Добавить `parameters[i] =  System.Convert.ChangeType(parameters[i],parameter.ParameterType)`  разобраться только с `i` переменной т.к. `i++` нужно в другое место поставить.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!